# Не могу интерпретировать результаты предсказаний сети

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, классификация

Я обучил бинарный классификатор но не могу интерпретировать результаты предсказаний. Подскажите пожалуйста я неверно интерпретирую результаты или сеть действительно выдает мусор? Если она выдает мусор то подскажите пожалуйста как это пофиксить.
Запустите этот [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zIRbIA8JZ5lV-Sito2ITxh13BTDWNFQq#scrollTo=ao8olnRGbKQn) и увидите результаты предсказаний о которых я говорю

**Дополнительная информация:**
Сеть обучалась 30 минут на 10000 train изображений для каждого класса и 3000 test изображений для каждого класса

**Как выглядят данные:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как выглядит график обучения:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как выглядит код обучения:**

```
# скачивание проекта
!wget https://github.com/gimaevra94/classifier/archive/refs/heads/main.zip

# распаковка проекта
!unzip /content/main.zip

# распаковка данных
!unzip /content/classifier-main/train_test.zip

# колбек рисующий график после каждой эпохи
!pip install livelossplot

# слои
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Rescaling
from tensorflow.keras.layers import RandomRotation
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D

# колбек, оптимизатор, модель сети и препроцессинг
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import Callback
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.utils import image_dataset_from_directory

# пути до папок
from pathlib import Path

# колбек рисующий график после каждой эпохи
from livelossplot import PlotLossesKeras

# создание каталогов под классы
path='/content'

base_dir=Path(path).parent/'content'
train_dir=base_dir/'train'
test_dir=base_dir/'test'

dog_dir=train_dir/'dog'
human_dir=train_dir/'human'

dog_dir=test_dir/'dog'
human_dir=test_dir/'human'

# изображения становятся одноканальными 80х80 с сохранением пропорций. train перемешивается
train = image_dataset_from_directory(directory=train_dir,
                                     labels='inferred',
                                     label_mode='binary',
                                     color_mode='grayscale',
                                     image_size=(80, 80),
                                     crop_to_aspect_ratio=True)

test = image_dataset_from_directory(directory=test_dir,
                                    labels='inferred',
                                    label_mode='binary',
                                    color_mode='grayscale',
                                    image_size=(80, 80),
                                    crop_to_aspect_ratio=True,
                                    shuffle=False)

# модель сети
model=Sequential([
    Input((80,80,1)),
    Rescaling(1./255),
    RandomRotation(factor=.2,fill_mode='nearest'),
    BatchNormalization(),

    Conv2D(16,3,padding='same',activation='relu'),
    BatchNormalization(),

    MaxPooling2D(2,None,'same'),
    BatchNormalization(),

    Conv2D(32,3,padding='same',activation='relu'),
    BatchNormalization(),

    MaxPooling2D(2,None,'same'),
    BatchNormalization(),

    Conv2D(64,3,padding='same',activation='relu'),
    BatchNormalization(),

    MaxPooling2D(2,None,'same'),
    BatchNormalization(),

    Flatten(),
    Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')])

# добавление в сеть ошибки, оптимизатора и метрики
model.compile(
    loss='binary_crossentropy',
    optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.000001),
    metrics='accuracy')

# обучение
history=model.fit(x=train,
                    epochs=30,
                    validation_data=test,
                    batch_size=64,
                    callbacks=PlotLossesKeras())

# сохранение
model.save('model.h5')
```